# $G=\langle a,b \rangle$, show $a^{p^3} \in Center(G)$

Tags: group-theory

Let G be a finite group of order $p^5$ where p is a prime and $G=\langle a,b \rangle$

where $|a|=p^4, b^p=a^p, bab^{-1}=a^{1+2p^3}$

Show that $a^{p^3} \in Center(G)$

For a it is trivial $aa^{p^3}a^{-1}=a^{p^3}$

For b the solution says $ba^{p^3}b^{-1}=ba^pa^pa^pb^{-1}=a^{p^3}$

My questions is if the solution for b is correct? For me it is incorrect that $a^{p^3}=a^pa^pa^p$. I would say that $a^pa^pa^p=a^{3p} \neq a^{p^3}$ or am I missing something here

Comment: Incidentally, you don't need either of the hypotheses $b^p=a^p$ or $bab^{-1} = a^{1+2p^3}$. It is enough to assume that $|G| = p^5$ and $a \in G$ with $|a| = p^4$. That is because $\langle a \rangle$ has index $p$ and so is normal in $G$, and hence $\langle a \rangle \cap Z(G)$ is non-trivial, so it must contain $a^{p^3}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's enough to show $b.a^{p^3}=a^{p^3}.b$ because any element of $G=\langle a,b \rangle$ is in the form $g=a^{n_1}b^{m_1}...a^{n_k}b^{m_k},\ k\in \mathbb{N}$ and if $b.a^{p^3}=a^{p^3}.b$ then $g.a^{p^3}=a^{p^3}.g$. So
$$b.a^{p^3}=b.(a^p)^{p^2}=b.(b^p)^{p^2}=b.b^{p^3}=b^{p^3}.b=a^{p^3}.b$$